# Rails nested resources and :path => "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

I have the following routes, which allows for urls like `/:username/:project_name`

```
resources :users, :path => "/" do
  resources :projects, :path => "/"
end
```

The problem is that `/:username/edit` doesn't work, because it is looking for a project with the name of 'edit'.

Any way around this? Thanks!

Comment: What url structure are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I wrote above, I am wanting urls like '/username/project_name' and '/username/project_name_2'. The problem is that this doesn't allow for '/username/edit'.

Comment: did you try to "manually" add this route? i would add a match "/username/edit" => "users#edit" before the resource path. and by the way, this routing setup is not a good idea. it will lead to more problems on the way...

Comment: Take off the path "/" on the projects resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple ways of doing this...

1) Will give you routes like `/:user_id/:id` (which you wanted)

```
match '/:user_id/edit', :to => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_user
resources :users, :except => [:edit], :path => "/" do
  resources :projects, :path => "/"
end
```

2) Will give you routes like `/:user_id/projects/:id` (which it seems like you're avoiding)

```
resources :users, :path => "/" do
  resources :projects
end
```

I personally prefer #2 since it is cleaner and provides more knowledge about the route at a glance.